# How to create a column in which its values are calculated based the differences between rows from other columns?

Tags: r

[image]

Given this dataframe imported into R, I want to create a clumn named 'Category' in which different categories will be assigned. The specifics for the assignment are that: 1) If SSR from 'Interpretation' is equal to or larger than 4 and the difference between SSR and ISR is larger than 1, then the category called 'A' is assigned; 2) If ISR from 'Interpretation' is equal to or larger than 4 and the difference between ISR and SSR is larger than 1, then the category called 'B' is assigned. Does anyone have any idea as to how to achieve it with R codes?

I tried 'mutate' function plus other functions, but it just didn't work out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check [here on how to ask a question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This really hurts in the eyes when running dark mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign different categories based on multiple logical conditions with `case_when()`. Before you do so, I suggest you tidy the data by reshaping it such that each variable (`ISR` and `SSR`) have their own column. To convert it back to your original format, use `pivot_longer()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Condition, ~Interpretation,      ~score,
        "UN",           "ISR",           4,
        "UN",           "SSR",           3,
        "UN",           "ISR",           7,
        "UN",           "SSR",           5,
        "UN",           "ISR", 4.666666667,
        "UN",           "SSR",           7,
        "UN",           "ISR", 2.666666667,
        "UN",           "SSR",           5,
        "UN",           "ISR", 4.333333333,
        "UN",           "SSR", 3.666666667
  )

# reshape wider
df <- df |> 
  mutate(id = rep(1:(nrow(df) / 2), each = 2)) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Interpretation, values_from = score) |> 
  unnest(c(ISR, SSR))

# classify
df |> 
  mutate(Category = case_when(
    SSR >= 4 & (SSR - ISR) > 1 ~ "A",
    ISR >= 4 & (ISR - SSR) > 1 ~ "B"
  ))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   Condition    id   ISR   SSR Category
#>   <chr>     <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
#> 1 UN            1  4     3    <NA>    
#> 2 UN            2  7     5    B       
#> 3 UN            3  4.67  7    A       
#> 4 UN            4  2.67  5    A       
#> 5 UN            5  4.33  3.67 <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @dufei for your input. This works so far. However, when I added an extra column in which each pair of 'ISR and SSR' comes from the same experiment participant such that before 'Condition', there is another column whose values from top to down are 'S1, S1, S2, S2, S3, S3, S4, S4, S5, S5', When I pipe this like 'df > group_by(Subject) .....' with your code, no column for 'category' is returned. Do you have any further ideas about it?